# Nvidia GRID NVIFR + NVENC H.264 video streaming concrete example

Tags: amazon-ec2, video-streaming, nvidia

I am running a rendering software on the AWS NVIDIA GRID EC2 instance and want stream the output of that renderer application to my local machine, to VLC if possible.

I've looked at Nvidia GRID SDK examples but it barely demonstrates streaming the output of an application. All the *NVIFR* examples show how to capture from a GL buffer but not from a renderer application. Is anyone aware of a solution?

Comment: hey blueskin, any update on this ? I'm trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: @MichalGallovic didn't pursue this after a few days since the project was discontinued. So am not sure if there's a solution

Comment: thank you for the answer, it surely isn't an easy one. We are trying to stream the application to browser (html5). Next week, I'm going to try binary.js combination with node.js getting h264 buffers from stdout/websocket with rendering done by broadway.js. Hope it will play out well (http://binaryjs.com/ https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway)